# Access violation error in OpenCL enqueueNDRangeKernel

Tags: kernel, opencl, gpu

I try to launch at least empty kernel with a lot of parameters but I got memory access violation in function enqueueNDRangeKernel. Please check my code, maybe I missed something or just didn't know.

Host code:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71256314/main.cpp
At first goes some initialization, then I create buffers, then set arguments. No errors come out. It crashes on first enqueueNDRangeKernel function call.

Kernel code:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71256314/baum_kernel.cl
It doesn't work even though kernel is empty.

Some problems with buffers I guess, but no errors are returned.

Versions:
AMD APP SDK v2.8 — AMD Catalyst™ 12.10 (9.002)
GPU: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650

Comment: Check the compiling and library linking. This looks like the program is not properly linked to OpenCL. The API should never crash in that way.

Comment: @DarkZeros I don't think this is the issue. I set up project in VS 2012 like it is desccribed here (for x64 system):
http://kode-stuff.blogspot.ru/2012/11/setting-up-opencl-in-visual-studio_1.html
I tried to run simple helloworld examples with this configuration and they worked fine.

Comment: Sry to tell you that the Hello world example they put is useless, just calls a function of OpenCL that runs nothing (just returns some IDs). Even if it works the linking might be wrong. Typical problems of the errors you are experiencing is linking with wrong library version or dynamic loading it in a wrong way.

Comment: @DarkZeros, well, thanks! I found out that SDK version was 2.8.1 actually and it is for newer drivers. So I downgraded SDK to 2.8.0 and now it doesn't crash.
Now I have error CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE, however I pass 1000 to as global NDRange and 100 as local NDRange while CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE is 256.

Comment: @DarkZeros Now it crashes again with access violation =(
And I tried to launch samples from Documents\AMD APP\samples\opencl and they work fine, even not simple ones. Even under x32 settings. What can it be then? The access violation is in amdocl.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The problem was in line

```
err = kernel.setArg(11, Otr);   checkErr(err, "Kernel::setArg()11");
```

I was passing pointer to float Otr instead of passing the corresponding OpenCL buffer Otr_b to setArg function. OpenCL had been trying to copy the pointer to kernel which was expecting buffer. No doubt there was access violation error.

---

2) Another important point mentioned by DarkZeros: check your library linking and also version correspondence between ATI driver and AMD APP SDK. Here is link where drivers and SDKs compatibility is listed: [Versions of AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-tools-sdks/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/download-archive/). I my case I had AMD APP SDK v2.8.1 which was not compatible with 12.10 (9.002) driver. I installed v2.8.0 version eventually.